# Use a bluetooth headset to transmit voice to a bluetooth speaker

Tags: bluetooth, speakers, headset

I have a [bluetooth headset](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Plantronics-Bluetooth-Headset-Voyager-Legend-black/dp/B08F2T5CJ8) and [a bluetooth speaker](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Ultimate-Ears-Wireless-Bluetooth-Waterproof/dp/B07G6MBCG3).

Is there a way I could connect these two devices together so that I could speak into the headset's mic and my voice heard on the speaker?

Comment: No.  Period.  No.  That isn't how it works.  Sure.. someone "could" design such a thing.  I am sure that your setup isn't that.

Comment: No, there isn't. Both are "clients". Both are functionally equivalent.

Comment: To further what @ChanganAuto is talking about.. from an embedded standpoint, almost any Bluetooth device can be both server and client.  Without programming to do so, this would never be built into devices like that even though they technically could.

Comment: I have an android phone, can I use my android phone as a proxy of sorts? I know I can use my phone to speak into the speaker but I am yet to find a way to speak to the headset and have that go into my speaker.

Comment: Yes, indeed.. it *could* be done that way but someone would have needed to make an app to bridge the gap.

Comment: I guess now the question becomes is there already an app that does this.

Comment: No, there isn't. One of the reasons is for that to work *both* speakers must be paired simultaneously with the phone, something not even possible until the Bluetooth 5.0 revision/version (and all peripherals must also be of that version or higher). Other reason is, obviously, lack of demand for such specific usage (this is the first time I've came across such feature request since Bluetooth exists!)

Comment: And questions about phones that aren't about their connection with a PC are off-topic here anyway.

Comment: There's then always the fun one of listening to any human trying to talk through a mic when their amplified voice is 50ms delayed. That runs the full gamut from mildly amusing to tiktok star ;)

Answer (score 1):

As stated by previous commenters, it is impossible due to the way those specific devices are designed and how they use Bluetooth technology. Like what [Señor CMasMas](https://superuser.com/users/1000631/se%c3%b1or-cmasmas) and [ChanganAuto](https://superuser.com/users/653259/changanauto) have already mentioned, you would not be able to achieve what you are looking for through simply connecting them together. You would have to code your own protocol in order to change their "client" role